# X++ mapping an imported text

Tags: maps, axapta, x++

Can anyone provide me with a help about how can I map containers?

For example if I a have text file, which I import, and as the code reads trough the file it needs to map the lines which start with the same value (for example 1).

So how can I check if that line exists and if it does then import it the table, if not make a new record. And so on ...

If code sample or anything else is needed, please ask!

Comment: Could you provide a code sample, an example of some lines from the text file and the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a TextIO to read a file record per record, you'll get a container for each line.

A container is a structure you can refer as a super array. It will allow you to store anything at each position of this array (string, int, object, etc...) regardless what's store in the rest of the container.

There are two ways get and set data in it. There are functions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa570072.aspx) or you can use brackets:

```
ItemId        itemId;
Qty           qty;
Price         price;
Container     c;

//Add two elements in the container
c = ["1001", 10];

//Add a third element at the end
c += [1.5];

//Get the elements 
[itemId, qty, price] = c;
```

So, it's a really versatile tool and it comes with a price. You can't manipulate it as a map or other collection classes.

Finally, the TexIO.read() method will get a container at each line, so you need to deal with it at each time. If you have a record identifier, a key and then data, it could be something like:

```
Container  c;
TextIO     file;
Map        map = new Map(Types::Integer, Types::Container);
int        identifier, key;
[...]

c = file.read();
while (c)
{
    [identifier, key] = c;
    if (identifier == 1 && !map.exists(key))
    {
        map.insert(key, c);
    }
    c = file.read();
}
```